# Hide labels and show buttons ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm looking to create a simple app which has motion/ touch events.

The aim is to start with the labels appearing:

1) If the screen is touch I would like it hide the labels and show four buttons.

2) If the screen is touched again, I would like it to hide the buttons and then show the labels.

At the same time I have implemented a pageView control which can allow users to slide along and look at four different screens. Both 1) and 2) will need to appear on all four view and function the same way.

Is this something that cn be done and what would be the best way? would it be switch statements or if statements? could someone please give me an example?

I already found some code on a previous post which said something like:

```
[label 1 setHidden:TRUE]
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Apologies for being a newbie.

I gave it a try but I seem to be getting red errors under titleLabel:

```
BOOL isTouchedFirst ;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if (isTouchedFirst) {
        NSLog(@"In touchesBegan");
        titleLabel.hidden = YES;
        //  button.hidden = NO ;
        isTouchedFirst = NO;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"In touchesBegan");
        titleLabel.hidden = NO;
        //  button.hidden = YES ;
        isTouchedFirst = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that your new and this is your first question but on stackoverflow we're not here to do it for you. We're here to help you with a specific problem with code you already have. So what have you tried already???? Provide us with some code of you attempting this and we will help. Also please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: Apologies. I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make `label.userInteractionEnabled = YES` for your labels.

Make a global  boolean variable

```
BOOL isTouchedFirst ;
```

After that use the following :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

     if (isTouchedFirst) {
         NSLog(@"In touchesBegan");
        label.hidden = YES;
        button.hidden = NO ;
        isTouchedFirst = NO;
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"In touchesBegan");
        label.hidden = NO;
        button.hidden = YES ;
        isTouchedFirst = YES;
     }

}
```

Comment: gave it a try above in my edit but it does seem to work.

Comment: is there a way of making it fade out rather than just vanish?

Comment: You have to use uiview animations

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UITapGesture` to detect the touches and Use the `BOOL` var to track the touches.